# How to move focus on previous field if the user press BackSpace on empty field?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

In NativeScript-core I have a series of textfields like on the picture:

[image]

The TextField is like:

```xml
<TextField text="{{ number }}" hint="" maxLength="1" keyboardType="number"/>
```

Is it possible to move focus on the previous filed if the user press BackSpace while on empty field?

Comment: The core framework doesn't provide any event for key press, you will have to override the [delegate method on ios](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/nativescript-core/ui/text-field/text-field.ios.ts#L76) / [text changed listener on android](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/nativescript-core/ui/editable-text-base/editable-text-base.android.ts#L67) to do achieve that.

Comment: If it's going to be just numbers, I think it's easier if you create your own keypad below these textfield, you will have more control over what is being pressed.